# При чтении свойства класса выводит "undefined", хотя при дампе экземпляра свойство есть

Tags: javascript

```
class ApiHandler {
    constructor(path, params = {}, token = null) {
        this.params = params;
        this.path = server + path;
        this.setHeader();
    }

    setHeader(token = null) {
        this.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        if (token) {
            this.header.push( {"Authorization": token} );
        }
    }

    get() {
        this.sendRequest("GET");
        return this;
    }

    post() {
        this.sendRequest("POST");
        return this;
    }

    destroy() {
        this.sendRequest("DELETE");
        return this;
    }

    async sendRequest(verb) {
        let r = null;
        await fetch(this.path, {
            method: verb,
            mode: "cors",
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(this.params)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            r = response;
        });

        this.response = r;
    }
}
```

Вот класс, который отвечает за доступ к api

```
loginSubmit(id, password) {
    let params = {id: id, password: password};
    let r = new ApiHandler("/auth/login", params);

    r.post();

    console.log("Дампаю экземпляр:");
    console.log(r); //свойство на месте

    console.log("Читаю свойство: " + r.response) //undefined 
 }
```

В методе создается экземпляр класса и делается запрос. Вот только свойство response оказывается undefined  при чтении, хотя при дампе самого экземпляра свойство на месте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`post` вызывает асинхронную функцию `sendRequest` без `await`, никакого ожидания не присходит. `post` сразу возвращается. `sendRequest` - ждет `fetch`. Свойство `this.response` остается неназначенным, в консоль выводится `undefined`. Тем временем, запрос возвращается, выполняется `then` и `this.response = r;`. Консоль обновляет свойства объекта `r`, который туда выведен, и Вы видите `response`.

Comment: ай-ай-ай ответы после закрытия :)

Comment: async post() {
        let r = await this.sendRequest("POST");
        this.response = r;
    } - метод должен быть переписан так, верно?